# ls with symbolic link source

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose I have the following shell output from `ls`:

```
>$ ls -lF
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root         admin   35 Aug  6 16:59 conf@ -> /Users/user/dev/pf/trunk/ext
drwxr-xr-x@ 5 user         admin  170 Aug  7 14:09 pf/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root         admin  102 Aug  6 15:27 risk/
```

So, how can I get the following output from, perhaps, `ls`:

```
conf@ -> /Users/user/dev/pf/trunk/ext
pf/
risk/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -lF | cut -c52-
```

This will give everything starting at column `52` and beyond

Answer (score 0):

just `cut` the results at correct point, e.g. `ls -lF |cut -c 52`